# What constitutes "multiple designs" on a PCB?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I notice a lot of PCB houses have a significant up-charge if you include more than one "design" in an order.

When you design a board to be broken into multiple pieces ("panels"), this makes some sense. However, what if a board doesn't have any panel cuts?

Now, I could see charging more to try to stop people taking advantage of minimum size based pricing to effectively get more than one final part out of a board. But e.g. PCBWay says "if it has more than one we will charge more, for same design there is no extra charge". This seems like a very arbitrary restriction; what is the cost difference to them between printing one design twice, or two different designs, or one larger design?

Then there's e.g. JLC which has this unhelpful Engrish:

> if the traces/ silkscreen in your PCB is different, as long as it can be separated, no matter by v-cut, millings, or drill holes, it will be regarded as different designs. One more thing, sometimes, even all your PCBs look the same, but if there is no any connection to make them into one panel, and it needs to be sent as single piece, it will be also considered as different designs.

...which sounds like it gives them enough wiggle room to make the decision arbitrarily.

...or does it? Am I overthinking this because I'm new to PCB manufacturing? JLC's page goes on to talk about v-cuts and packaging and stuff that makes no sense in terms of what I would call "a single board".

Are "multiple designs" just what happens when you take a *total fabrication area* and use edge cuts to turn it into smaller pieces? (But how is that different from "panels"... because panels aren't fully cut before shipping?) Can I put whatever I want on a single 'cut' and have it count as one "design", *even if I obviously intend to slice that up myself*?

...and if that's the case, why would anyone ever place a multiple-"designs" order when it seems to be *significantly* cheaper to order each design separately? (Maybe this only holds for "bargain-price" 2-layer boards with no frills?)

Comment: I'd say it is up to the manufacturer and is not carved in stone. These are private companies that set the rules. 
If they review your order and suspect that it might be several designs, they don't have to prove anything.

Comment: I tried just that with JLC, one panel with multiple designs and hole pattern for break-away so they charged me for every “individual” board within the panel. Still very affordable.

Comment: I sent a design to JLC PCB that was many pieces (but left intact so I would have to cut it out myself) and they built it and shipped it to me. When I re-submitted it a second time they rejected it. I think some of their lowest cost options are loss-leader introductory offers. So they have to restrict them to avoid losing money.

Comment: Inventory management software makes people do lots of weird things.  I've had to split orders up into a shipment of $1000s of parts and a shipment of a single 0805 resistor because the resistor was for R&D and the other parts were for production.

Comment: If they flag something that's not actually (e.g. an isolation barrier), just kindly ask them to process as single.  Or go somewhere else -- these are **cheap** services, they won't miss your purchase nor will anyone else be starving for yours; just shop around and find the deal you like.

Comment: Last Autumn I did an experiment with JLC PCB pricing. Unfortunately I don't have the figures to hand so I'm inventing the costs, but they aren't far from the truth.  It depends a lot on the layout. Roughly, a single small board, say 2X3cm would cost £x for a minimum order of 5 pieces. Multiply these up into a 6X6 cm board (6 copies) and the price goes up to 2.5*£x, so half the price of 1 board. Change the layout to 9X4cm and you might pay 3*£x. Double the size again to 8X9cm (12 copies) and you only pay 4*£x. It's worth playing around with the configuration to get the best price.

Answer (score 2):

Last year, I sent in a board to JLCPCB. I got the same price change, because of multiple designs on the board. I solved it by simply removing the v-cut, and just used all the available space 100 X 100 to cram in as many designs as possible, and did the cutting myself. These were prototypes anyway, so I did not mind. I used a tile cutter to cut, and made sure there was about 2mm space, the same width as the cutting disc on my saw. I think I saved a lot of time too, not having to wait for a rejection, and having to redesign to comply to the rules. With that said, these productions are dirt cheap, and I never make only 5, I always choose 10pcs, its cheaper if you need them all.

Comment: Please answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> "if it has more than one we will charge more, for same design there
> is no extra charge"

Thats up to the manufacturer to determine and it varies from manufacture to manufacturer. I'd imagine that v-scoring is a good indicator of two seperate designs. The manufacturer determines this.

Other than that there are not any standard ways that define multiple designs.

Comment: This makes me wonder if they don't really care *except* that they charge extra for v-scoring. Charging extra for a special process that many orders don't use would make sense. (But then, why wouldn't they just say that?)

Comment: There are other reasons for not wanting multiple designs, and a few that I can think of is workflow and software. It may be harder for PCB way to combine multiple designs on a panel if the customer has already done that. Imagine issues a PCB fab could have in errors (maybe they cut the customers design when they shouldn't) so just easier to tell everyone, no multiple designs.